# Why does `printf` with `%hu%` takes 4 bytes from stack instead 2?

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, nasm, calling-convention

I am studying assembly basics and I use `printf` quite often (which I thought I know good enough from C/C++ experience). I came across weird thing with 2 bytes (16 bits) values:

In 32 bit mode, when using `printf("%hu", (unsigned short)123)`, I thought it would take off 6 bytes from stack (4 for address of format string, and 2 for value). Meanwhile reality is, it 4 for address and 4 for value.

**Why is that?** Is `%hu` equal to just `%u`?  Or is it just stripping high 2 bytes of the value?

---

Some code (from C to ASM compiling, `-O0`):
https://godbolt.org/z/x167zdon1

This works:

```
        mov     eax, 123
        push    eax
        push    format ; "%hu"
        call    _printf
        add     esp, 4 + 4    ; works
```

But I thought this should:

```
        mov     ax, 123
        push    eax
        push    format ; "%hu"
        call    _printf
        add     esp, 4 + 2    ; doesn't work: print gibberish, as it takes 2 bytes more to display the value....
```

Comment: Even if you did not consider `printf` **you** have pushed `eax` which is 4 bytes. But `printf` being variadic, standard C type promotions apply, your `unsigned short` will be passed as `unsigned int`, 4 bytes again. Even if you ignore all of those, the calling convention still says to pass arguments padded to multiples of 4 bytes.

Comment: alignment......

Comment: Can you please post it as answer, so I can mark it as valid answer?

Comment: "print gibberish"?  Your 2nd version should still correctly print the low 2 bytes of the dword you pushed, and then mess up the stack and crash.  Oh, I guess since you don't print a newline, with line-buffered stdout you'd crash before returning from main, and thus not get output.  Leaving high garbage in EAX before you push it is equivalent to something like `printf("%hu", 0x12000012)` which as we can see does ignore the high garbage and prints just the low 2 bytes.  https://godbolt.org/z/Ecdn75GYa

Comment: same reason `printf("%f", 0.1f)` will read 8 bytes on common platforms. Read about variadic default promotion in C for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't work ...

Sure: You performed a `push eax`, which pushes 4 bytes on the stack. For this reason, you have to remove the 4 bytes from the stack again.

> I came across weird thing with 2 bytes (16 bits) values.

In x86-32 code, the stack should typically be aligned to 4. This means that the `esp` register's value shall be a multiple of 4.

For this reason, most calling conventions require pushing a 32-bit value if the function argument is only a 16- or even an 8-byte value.

> Is `%hu` equal to just `%u`? Or is it just stripping high 2 bytes of the value?

It depends on the calling convention and the library implementation:

When using a calling convention where the C compiler has to `push` a 32-bit number whose upper 16 bits are 0 if the argument is a 16-bit value, the library (the `printf` function) *may* be implemented in a way that `%hu` is identical to `%u`.

When a calling convention is used where the upper 16 bits of such a number may have any value, the `printf` function must strip the upper 2 bytes, of course.

**Edit**

Actually, you have **two** effects in the `printf` example:

1. As I have already written, an x86-32 compiler will pass 32-bit values to a function if a `char` or `short` argument is expected.
2. In functions with a variable number of arguments (such as `printf`), the "additional" arguments of the type `char` or `short` must be cast to `int` by the compiler.

Let's assume we work on a 16-bit CPU but the data type `int` is 32 bits long. And we have some function `void test(short x, ...);`.

If we call `test(a, a);` in this situation, the compiler will pass the first argument as 16-bit value (because the argument has the data type `short`) and the second argument as 32-bit value (because it is an additional argument).

The same is the case for the additional arguments of `printf()` - assuming that `int` is a 32-bit data type.